# Ruby jsonapi-resources links (relative/absolute)

Tags: ruby, jsonapi-resources

I am incredibly new to Ruby, so I apologise in advance if this question seems very simple or vague.

Where, when using `jsonapi-resources` is the base path for JSON API links specified? I wish to change from specifying full URLs to `root-relative` paths to these resources.

I've found the `routes.rb` which has

```ruby
Rails.application.routes.draw do

# Route / to the front-end
root to: 'root#index'

namespace :api do

   jsonapi_resources :widgets

   // ...more jsonapi_resources calls
end
```

Comment: can you show some code on what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: I'm looking at a lot of existing code and want to know what sort of command, configuration or class initialisation that would set this up

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you are looking for something like this?

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :api do
    namespace :v1 do
      jsonapi_resources :cars, only: [:index]
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I've found something similar:
`jsonapi_resources :widgets`

What sets the response to generate full/partial link paths?

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to achieve here. Could you update your question with a more precise description of what you are trying to do and how?

Comment: I want to change all links fields returned in responses from say `self: "http://192.168.0.1:3000/api/widgets/object_id"}` to `{self: "/api/widgets/object_id"}`